# Different events when onclick tabs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have created a tabs by jquery and i want to display different data from database at each tab how can i do that knowing that it is the same container and same data but with different conditions hope to find an answer soon
And i am using php and javascript
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a map of tab IDs to remote URLs you want to call when the tab is clicked.  For example, in JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mySources = [];
    mySources['home'] = '/ajax/getHome.php';
    mySources['about'] = '/ajax/getAbout.php';
</script>
```

And, when your page is being built, it's easy to add the click listeners and ajax calls:

```
$(function(){
    $("#myTabContainer a.tabLink").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        url = mySources[this.id];
        $.get(url,null,
            function(data){
                // this is the data returned by the server, 
                // put it wherever it needs to go
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Just my $.02, but that'd be how I'd start it, at least.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you can set on event on the tabs (#('tabs').bind('tabselect', 'doSomething()')) and inside doSomething call an ajax method

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want to ajax the tab content based on which tab is clicked?
Or do you really want diferent content when clicking the same tab, depending on some condition?

Comment: yes ajax tab content based on which one clicked how can i do this